# How to make image scale to full width on bootstrap column after transition to mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with making the image on the right stretch to full width in a moment when you'll make the screen size smaller so it transitions to mobile view.
Is there any other class in bootstrap that would do similar work that "img-fluid" does but display image full width when it goes below the text in bootstrap grid system?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
<div class="align-self-center">
<p class="lead font-weight-bold">sometext</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="someimage.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/2220/
To see what I mean simply lower the width of display window. Image goes below the text and fills only half of the div when I want it to fill it fully and behave as it does right now before the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the columns should have the same breakpoint (ie; `md`/`sm`) so that they become full-width at the same time...

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
      <div class="align-self-center">
       <p class="lead font-weight-bold">sometext</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="someimage.jpg">
     </div>
   </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwnu5zjq/

Comment: I've completely missed a fact that those column classes do not match. I was wondering why it would work like this for way too long. Yes it solves it.